# vba doble bucle con count

Tags: excel, vba

Quiero hacer un doble bucle en vba excel, la idea es que tendria una columna A que contiene nombres de tiendas, en esta columna se me repiten las tiendas y luego en una columna D por ejemplo, tengo anotados los nombres de tiendas sin repetciones, lo que quiero es ejecutar un bucle que recorre a la columna A y cuenta las tiendas, si la condicion es true en la columna E al lado de cada nombre de tienda me hace un count... se os ocurre como puedo hacerlo? Tengo hecho este procedimiento pero me cuenta mal las tiendas, da resultado incorrecto

```
Sub adaptandoBucles()
Dim mitienda(3) As String

mitienda(0) = "BALENRAIMAD06"
mitienda(1) = "PASBCN04"
mitienda(2) = "SERRMAD01"
mitienda(3) = "BVPASBCN10"

Dim i As Integer


Dim count As Integer

For j = LBound(mitienda) To UBound(mitienda)

    Range("c1").Select ' si en mi celda c1 tengo a tiendas de j
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = mitienda(j) Then

            Range("e1").Select
            For k = 1 To 4
                If Cells(k, 5).Value Like mitienda(j) Then
                    count = 1
                    Cells(k, 6).Value = Cells(k, 6).Value + count
                Else
                count = 0
                End If
            Next k

        Else
        count = 0
        End If
    Next i
count = 0
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: No necesitas vba para esto... un simple `=CONTAR.SI(A:A;E1)` te cuenta cuántas veces aparece la tienda de la celda E1 en la columna A

Comment: Hola Damian, gracias por tu respuesta, no me sirve de mucho porque esta es una pequeña parte de un procedmiento con muchos pasos que tengo, entonces necesito desarroyar esta parte programandola ya que forma parte de un todo. Si no haria una simple tabla dinamica jejeje.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo tienes los datos, y del resultado esperado? Creo que un diccionario es tu solución...

Comment: Hola Elier,si disculpa que no esta muy bien especificado, tambien se agradeceria que pudiera poner aqui una imagen del excel con el cuadro pero por desgracia no me deja o no se hacerlo... de todas maneras ya lo he solucionado con un par de cambios en el bucle, gracias a todos igualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues esto debería servirte Carlos:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ContarTiendas()

    Dim C As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NombreHoja") 'Esto se refiere al libro que contiene el código, cambia NombreHoja por el nombre de tu hoja
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'última fila en la columna que contiene las tiendas (sólo una fila por tienda)
        For Each C In .Range("E1:E" & LastRow) 'bucle por todas las tiendas
            C.Offset(0, 1) = Application.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), C) 'contar.si para cada tienda
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: muy bueno, funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias Daniam. El loop es genial.